# Why is Spring Security's SessionManagementFilter running when my session creation policy is set to STATELESS?

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security, stateless-session

I have a J2EE REST-based web application that uses Spring Security 4.0.1.RELEASE. I am configuring Spring Security with a Java-based configuration and have set the session creation policy to STATELESS like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(secureEnabled=true, prePostEnabled=true, jsr250Enabled=true, order=1)
public class DefaultSecurityBeansConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    // ...
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()...; // additional config omitted for brevity
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

After reading [this article](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session) about Spring Security session management, I believe that the `SessionManagementFilter` filter should **not** be running in Spring Security's filter chain. But it definitely is. I can set a breakpoint in that class's `doFilter` method, and it is run on every request to the server.

What is going on here? The fact that this filter is running is causing other unexpected behavior in my app that I thought had been configured away.

Thanks.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. It still will run but it won't create a session or store stuff in the session. There will be a `SessionManagementFilter` with a `NullSecurityContextRepository` which won't store it. So basically it will always run but depending on the configuration it will do something or not.

Comment: Ok, that makes some sense. But when it runs, it's hardly a no-op. The `doFilter` method calls an `onAuthentication` method, which has registered as its only delegate strategy the `ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy`. This would seem to conflict with my `STATELESS` session creation policy. I don't have a session fixation strategy explicitly set, which if I'm not mistaken will default to `migrateSession`, but this behavior implies I'm somehow using `changeSessionId`. I may end up posting a new question with these findings.

Comment: Which shouldn't be an issue as you don't create a session (at least Spring Security doesn't create a session which doesn't mean that there isn't something else creating a session!) that should basically be a noop. As the strategy first checks if there already is a session if not, do nothing. The fact that Spring Security operates in stateless mode doesn't mean the rest of your application automatically becomes stateless!

Comment: To be sure, my appication **is** creating a session using an always-running servlet filter (`((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession()`). And this `ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy` that is running keeps changing my JSESSIONID. According to Spring docs, the NEVER value of `SessionCreationPolicy` is supposed to make use of the `HttpSession` if it exists, while the STATELESS value "will never create an HttpSession and will never use it to obtain the `SecurityContext`". To me, that sounds like it shouldn't be messing with my JSESSIONID. I'm just really confused why it's interfering.

Comment: It is interfering because operating in stateless mode and prevent session fixation attacks are 2 different things. What is happening here is that Spring Security detects the session and by default the security applied to prevent session hijacking is to change the session id. If you don't want that specify it to be none through `sessionFixation().none()`. However this will make your application less secure and vulnerable to session fixation attacks. I fail to see why changing the sessionid would break things, what is breaking be fixed instead of making your app less secure.

Comment: Thanks. Can you consolidate your comments into an answer that I can accept?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using Spring Security, session management is broader than storing the authenticated user in the session (as explained in the [Session Management Section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/session-mgmt.html) of the Spring Security Guide).

> HTTP session related functionality is handled by a combination of the `SessionManagementFilter` and the `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` interface, which the filter delegates to. Typical usage includes session-fixation protection attack prevention, detection of session timeouts and restrictions on how many sessions an authenticated user may have open concurrently.

Saying `sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)` doesn't mean that your application is stateless, it means that Spring Security won't create a session. If there is something else in your application still creating a session, Spring Security will try to protect it from a session-fixation attack.

How a session-fixation attack is done depends on the configured strategy; the default is to change the session identifier on each request. In Servlet 3.1 and newer containers, the `ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy` is the default if no explicit configuration is done. In Servlet 3.0 and below, the default is `migrateSession`.

You can disable session-fixation protection by doing `sessionFixation().none()`; however, you have to question if that is what you really want as that, potentially, makes your application less safe.

Depending on what breaks/fails you might want to fix that instead of making your application less secure.